# My cookie doesn't seem to be getting added to HttpsUrlConnection in Android

Tags: java, android, cookies, http-headers

Im writing a post method that needs to attach a session cookie to the request. I open up a secure SSL connection with the `HttpsUrlConnection` class. This works fine. I add a cookie to the connection by calling `connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", TheCookieData)`. 


     Unfortunately my server returns a 500 which I suspect has to do with not having a cookie or a correct cookie, attached to the post request. After, I add the cookie to the connection with `setRequestProperty` I check to see if the connection now has the cookie by logging `Log.i(TAG, "Post cookie header = " + connection.getHeaderField("Cookie"));` But this returns `null`. 


**Question** --> Am I adding the cookie correctly, if so why is `getHeaderField("Cookie")` returning `null`?

**The Post Method**

```
public static boolean post(Object message, Context context) {
    try {
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) setupConnection(HttpMethod.POST);
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(getSslContext(context).getSocketFactory());

        if(TheCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().size() > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "post found cookie " + TextUtils.join(";", TheCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",  TextUtils.join(";", TheCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()));
        }

        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("msg", message);
        Log.i(TAG, "post data=" + data.toString());
        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(data.toString().getBytes(UTF8));
        os.flush();

        Log.i(TAG, "Post cookie header = " + connection.getHeaderField("Cookie"));


        int code = connection.getResponseCode();

        connection.disconnect();

        Log.i(TAG, "post data fed to server!, data= " + data.toString());
        Log.i(TAG, "server responded with " + String.valueOf(code));

        return code != 200;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks right.

The reason you get a null is because you cant query headers until you connect.

From the URLConnection javadoc:

> The following methods are used to access the header fields and the 
>   contents AFTER the connection is made to the remote object:
>
> - getContent
> - getHeaderField
> - getInputStream
> - getOutputStream

Are you certain this is where your server errors?

Comment: The HttpUrlConnection method getErrorStream is useful for debugging such errors.

Comment: I cant be sure if its the problem because Im not server admin. The errorStream wasn't to helpful `The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.`

Comment: I take it your setupConnection method sets connection.setDoOutput(true)?

Comment: And you are setting the correct "Content-Type" header that your server is listening out for? Eg, connection.setRequestProperty("Content_Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");